# Replace ../IMG/xEPI_STOPPED_TOT.gif with <img src="">

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I would like to replace with javascript all image paths from a string with the img tag. Would I need a reg exp for this or a script ?

Image name and ext can be different in my string. In other words I have different images.

Replace ../IMG/epi.gif with

```
<img src="img/epi.gif">
```

initial string

"This image ../IMG/epi.gif and this image ../IMG/secondImage.jpg are not good"

needed result will be

```
'This image <img src="img/epi.gif"/> and this image <img src="img/secondImage.jpg"/> are not good'
```

Comment: Is the lowercasing of the image path intentional?

Comment: Yes It is and also the ../ is missing

Comment: By the way all images start with ../IMG and they end with the extention .gif or .jpg ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

**update**

```js
var img = 'This image ../IMG/epi.gif and this image ../IMG/secondImage.jpg are not good';
var newImg = img.replace(/\.\.\/IMG\/([^\.]+)(\.jpg|\.gif)/gi, '<img src="img/$1$2">');
alert (newImg);
```

Comment: Sorry I have tried this still does not work for this string "This image ../IMG/epi.gif and this image ../IMG/secondImage.jpg are not good"

Answer (score 0):

```js
var img = '../IMG/xEPI_STOPPED_TOT.gif';
var newImg = img.replace(/\.\.\/IMG\/(.*)/, '<img src="img/$1">');
alert (newImg);
```

Comment: What? It matches anything after ../IMG/

Comment: Sorry. Too early. I'll go get more coffee

Comment: I'm not entirely off though. Try it on the string `asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf ../IMG/xEPI_STOPPED_TOT.gif asdf`. You'll catch the ` asdf` at the end, so you'll need the file extension as a delimiter.

Comment: Sure, but those details weren't included in the question. If he wants/needs a more refined regex, he needs to provide a better understanding of the input data.

Comment: Ugh. Too late. Need to go to bed. I could have just added the extension check in 5 seconds instead of arguing about it.